# 'If' conditional works with NSLog but not without? Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I hope this question is some what self explanatory.

This works, returns YES and NO: *note the NSLog()'s*

```
- (BOOL)dateTestCourse:(NSDictionary *)listing {
    BOOL result =  ([self exammpleTest] == 0) ? YES : NO;
    if (result) {
        NSLog(@"Passes Test");
        return YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"Failed Test");
    return NO;

}
```

But below always return YES? Only difference is no NSLog();

```
- (BOOL)dateTestCourse:(NSDictionary *)listing {
    BOOL result =  ([self exammpleTest] == 0) ? YES : NO;
    if (result) {
        // NSLog(@"Passes Test");
        return YES;

    }
    // NSLog(@"Failed Test");
    return NO;

}
```

Is this something to do with C? I have no idea? I might expect it always to return NO (if I shouldn't be breaking in the conditional), but surely that would return YES.

I know I should be returning result in the above examples, but I'm curious to know why.

Comment: Are you sure the parenthesis are exactly as in your production code?

Comment: Could you show us the exammpleTest method?

Comment: I'm hesitant to as it's large-ish but is returning a BOOL correctly. Could the syntax of example method break the syntax of the dateTestCourse method? (or I'm doing something stupid)

Answer (score 1):

These two blocks of code should be running the same.  Are you perhaps doing a find/replace all on NSLog? That could be causing issues elsewhere, say with the exammpleTest(sic) method.

Also, the ternary operator on the second line is redundant, consider reducing that line to:

```
BOOL result =  ([self exammpleTest] == 0);
```